# URLFOR not working with nested expression

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to dynamically resolve to an images url by using:

```
<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyImageResource, '/images/{!object.Image__c}')}" />
```

I would expect the:
    `{!object.Image__c}`

to resolve to a value as these expressions do inside other strings, but unfortunately the output I get is:

```
<img src="/blahblah/resource/767676767/#{object.Image__c}" />
```

Firstly, is there a reason why the expression is not resolving?
Secondly, is there a way I can resolve the image url without resorting to doing it all in the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to insert `{ }` twice to the expression:

```
<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyImageResource, '/images/'+object.Image__c)}" />
```